# Write to unallocated space on LVM2

Tags: linux, partition, lvm

I was wondering if there is a way to write to the unallocated space of an lvm2 (linux)...

I prefer to have all my partitions encrypted but I'm not quite sure if there were any non-encrypted partitions earlier so now I want to overwrite/swipe all the space that is used by my LVM but not allocated to a logical volume right now.

I know creating a new logical volume consuming all the available extents, do the the wiping and then remove it afterwards would probably do the job (would it?) but I wonder if there is another, more elegant way that would allow me to do something like:

`dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/the-magical-unallocated-space-on-lvm2-device`

Comment: You'll probably want to use /dev/urandom since /dev/random on Linux will block when you run out of unused entropy bits. Of course, writing pseudorandom bits to a large volume will be painfully slow, and I've run across discussions suggesting that writing zeroes is secure enough for most, if not all, consumer and commercial applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no such system in LVM. It wouldn't be especially useful.

Filling the disk with a new logical volume and writing to it would probably do most of the job, but it is kind of messy.

I think the easiest way to do what you want to do is the following:

1. Add a new disk to the system
2. Create a new physical volume on it.
3. Migrate the logical volumes of the physical volumes that you worry about
4. Remove the empty physical volume from lvm
5. Do a secure erase of the disk
6. Recreate the physical volume
7. Migrate the logical volumes back.

I strongly recommend a backup before doing that manoeuvre.

Comment: I think secure erasing the entire disk would be overkill if only part of it is suspected of containing unencrypted data, but I guess it depends on your level of paranoia.  :D

Comment: Most modern harddisks supports secure erase in firmware, which is quicker than doing the old dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/hda method.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the method you've already described (creating a new logical volume and filling it) is the easiest solution.

You can also do a secure wipe, as pehrs suggests, but unless you're ultra-paranoid, I would think wiping just the "unused" space is sufficient.